# CASE statement syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to write a case statement, but running into some issues.  It is returning `incorrect syntax near '='`

```
SELECT
    customer_name,
    customer_initial_purchase_date,
    customer_purchase_date,
    CASE 'repeat_cust'
        WHEN
            customer_initial_purchase_date = customer_purchase_date
        THEN
            'new_cust'
        ELSE
            'repeat_cust'
    END
FROM
    sales
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT customer_name
    ,customer_initial_purchase_date
    ,customer_purchase_date
    ,CASE WHEN customer_initial_purchase_date = customer_purchase_date
          THEN 'new_cust'
          ELSE 'repeat_cust'
     END
FROM sales
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be confused by the two different ways of using [`case` expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx). One, called "simple" is like:

```
CASE <expression> WHEN <match 1> THEN <result 1>
    WHEN <match 2> THEN <result 2>
    ELSE <else result>
END
```

Note, there are no Boolean expressions in the simple `case` expression. When SQL Server saw, `CASE 'repeat_cust'` it thought it was dealing with the simple `case` expression and got confused by the `=` sign later.

The "searched" version is:

```
CASE WHEN <boolean expression 1> THEN <result 1>
    WHEN <boolean expression 2> THEN <result 2>
    ELSE <else result>
END
```

Simple can always be rewritten as searched, but not vice versa:

```
CASE WHEN <expression> = <match 1> THEN <result 1>
    WHEN <expression> = <match 2> THEN <result 2>
    ELSE <else result>
END
```